# Find all the real values of x for which $\sum _1^\infty x^n/n$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Find all the real values of $x$ for which $\sum_1^{\infty}(x^n/n)$  converges.

I began with the ratio test to get $nx/(n+1)$ but I'm not sure where to go next. I think I'm supposed to use Leibniz's Theorem at some point?

Comment: You should have $x^n$ in the denominator ?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a typo, I'll correct it.

Answer (score 3):

$$a_n:=\frac{x^n}{n}\Longrightarrow \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\left|\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\frac{n}{x^n}\right|=|x|\frac{n}{n+1}\xrightarrow [n\to\infty]{}|x|$$

Thus, the series converges for $\,-1<x<1\,$ , and it's easy to see that it also converges for $\,x=-1\,$ (Leibnitz series)

Comment: That doesn't really make it any clearer; would the last term not tend to 0 as n tended to infinity? Also, how is it 'easy to see' that it converges for x=-1? How have you used Leibniz's theorem?

Comment: Are you familiar with the alternating series test, Mathlete?

Comment: Mathlete, when $n=1000000000000$, is $n/(n+1)$ close to zero? or is it close to $1$?

Comment: OK I see what @DonAntonio meant now.